# Problem to call/use .js file (jquery function)

Tags: jquery

I have this jq function to open a link inside a div:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#all').delegate('a', 'click' (function() {
        $('#content').empty();
        var page = $(this).attr("id");
        $('#content').load("scripts/loop_a.php?page=" + page);
    });
});
```

I call this inside the head tag of my index.php and is working for all links that are in my header_template.php

If I load a new.php page inside my main_body div and it has a link inside, that link does not work with my script, (basically my new.php page doesn't see my .js file).

Is there a way to make it work for any new .php file that I open by calling the .js file only in my index.php?

Thank you

Edit... Solution Found... I edided the script above.

In my index.php I am using  which includes everything that happens.
So I just chose that div and I delegate all the functions that I needed to work when loading/opening new.php files.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#all').delegate('a', 'click' (function() { 
        $('#content').empty(); 
        var page = $(this).attr("id"); 
        $('#content').load("scripts/loop_a.php?page=" + page); 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements injected via ajax need to have event handlers rebinded to them, or alternatively event handlers *delegated* to a suitable parent/container:

```
$('#content').delegate("a", "click", function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); // perhaps you need this?
    $('#content').empty();
    var page = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#content').load("scripts/loop_a.php?page="+ page);      
});
```

See:

- http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
- http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/

Note: if you're using < jQuery 1.4.2, you will need to use [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live) instead.

Comment: most likely `.trg_div` and the `a` links are inside the `#content`. So the `delegate` will not work since the `.trgt_div` gets overwritten.. Better to bind to the `#content`.

Comment: @karim I am a bit confused here. I have links in my header, wich use my class .trgt_div as I showed. The one you suggest will work for the links inside my #content. So I should use both of them?

Comment: @karim79 "Not all events bubble. The blur, focus, load and unload events don’t bubble like other events." Is this true? If yes that means I cannot succed what I need?

Answer (score 0):

You may need a [live event](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.trgt_div > a').live('click', function() {
        $('#content').empty();
        var page = $(this).attr("id");
        $('#content').load("scripts/loop_a.php?page=" + page);
    });
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: hm... I will give it a try also... but why is karim saying that I should use that if I have jq< 1.4.2?

Comment: Ok.. I thought live was newer than delegate... My mistake.

Comment: The easier way is to use live events. If you think you will have to add lots (maybe in the order of a hundred?) of listeners to what comes in your ajax response then delegates are the way to go. If you are just expecting to add a couple of listeners live events is the simpler thing to do